# Upload Video From React-Native to Node.js server using

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, video, file-upload

I'm Using Image picker from react native image picker and I'm trying to upload a video but couldn't do so and I don't find any authentic solution for my code if anyone could be of any help it would be highly appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdBZ2.png)

Answer (score -1):

For video selecting you can use this package

npm i react-native-image-video-picker-editor

and upload the video as formData.